# Is there any restriction on how many files can be opened using fstream.h (practically)

Tags: c++

**Clarification:** This is not a duplicate because
 - I am also closing the files after opening them.
 - The program hangs after 20-40 iterations, not a few hundred as said in the other question

I was trying to create a simple puzzle in the form of 2000 files that will have numbers stored inside them. I needn't get into the details but basically it required a loop that would open and close 2000 files. However, after 20-40  iterations, the program would unexpectedly start hanging and not resume, neither give any error, etc. I went through the syntax of the program and everything else looks fine, so is the problem simply that C++ does not support such a large number of files?

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream out;
    char a[4];
    int i,j,k,n,no[5],queue[2000],q=1; //n = no of nos, q=first free index in queue
    queue[0]=1;
    bool successful;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i=0;i<2000;++i)
    {
        cout<<"\n\nIteration "<<i;
        snprintf(a,sizeof(a),"%d",queue[i]);
        out.open(a);
        cout<<"\nFile "<<a<<" opened\n";
        n=rand()%4+2;
        cout<<n<<" random nos to be generated";
        for(j=0;j<n;++j)
        {
            no[j]=rand()%2000+1;
            do
            {
                successful=true;
                for(k=0;k<i;++k)
                    if(queue[k]==no[j])
                        successful=false;
            } while (!successful);
        }
        cout<<"\nNos selected ";
        for(j=0;j<n;++j)
            cout<<no[j]<<" ";
        for(j=0;j<n;++j)
            out<<no[j]<<"\n";
        cout<<"\nWritten to file";
        out.close();
        out.open("logs", ios::app);
        cout<<"\nLogs opened";
        out<<"\n\n"<<i<<"\n ";
        for(j=0;j<n;++j)
            out<<no[j]<<"\n ";
        out.close();
        cout<<"\nLog entry made";

        for(j=0;j<n;++j)
            queue[q+j]=no[j];
        q+=n;
        cout<<"\nAppended to queue, new queue length: "<<q<<"\n\n";

    }

}
```

Comment: 2000 files is a rather big number. Yes, this will create problems.

Comment: In case you are working on linux refer to the answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux/36842#36842) please.

Comment: Anyone remembers FILES=20 BUFFERS=30 from the DOS era :)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is not a dup. Just wrong wording. The OP never has 2000 files open simultaneously. Each iteration opens _and closes_ the file. Consider reopening.

Comment: @user58697 _"Consider reopening."_ Actually not. If the OP needs to differentiate their problem (or someone does that for them), I'd be willing. If the question has a different problem this should be clarified.

Comment: @user58697 Edited. Can it be reopened now?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Is it Ok now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with opening files. The program hangs in an infinite loop at lines 28-34 while(!successful).

Comment: Tysm! That was rather dumb of me, anyways I've edited it. It now runs to abt 550 iterations, which is enough.